# Symfony Doctrine UniqueEntity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have UniqueEntity field email and I use SoftDeleteable

```
        filters:
        softdeleteable:
            class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
            enabled: true


 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields="email",
 *     errorPath="not valid",
 *     message="This email is already in use."
 * )
```

and when in my DB I have user with deletedAt some date and find entity by email

```
$user_by_email = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->findOneByEmail($email);
```

I have null and this is ok. But when I create new user I have error

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'wwwwwdww@1111.com' for key 'UNIQ_1483A5E9E7927C74'",
```

this my action. But have error when flush, when validate not error. Help

```
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $data = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($data, 'json');
        $user = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($data, 'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users', 'json');

        if (count($errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($user)) > 0) {
            $view = $this->view((string) $errors, 400);

            return $this->handleView($view);
        }

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a unique constraint on `email`, and you try to insert a new user with an already existing email .. so the error makes perfect sense.

**SoftDeleteable** merely adds a flag in your DB, but do not change the way unique fields are managed.

What you can do, though, is to make the pair `email` and `deleted_at` unique, instead of just the `email` field. You will only get this error when there is a not deleted row where email is the same.

Or, alternatively, delete the email when you "soft delete" a user, for instance. But I don't recommend it.

Comment: "What you can do, though, is to make the pair email and deleted_at unique, instead of just the email field. You will only get this error when there is a not deleted row where email is the same." The thing with that approach is that this will lead to an error as soon as the second entry is deleted too.

Comment: I'd say that it's up to the OP to ensure that if someone tries to "signup" or "create an account" with an email that already exists in the DB but is soft deleted, then the account will be "undeleted" rather than creating a new one. But theoretically, you are right @xabbuh

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to clarify that because you might easily forgot about this case.

Comment: Maybe to disable softdeleteable when create new entity?

Comment: or if I change field email -> array, and how SoftDeleteable work for this situation, check unique array ?

Comment: I don't really think that's a good idea. I'd say : create a `old_email` column (non-unique) that you set to `email` when you soft delete a user. And then empty the `email` column. And you're all set.

Comment: No worries. Please upvote or mark the answer if you found it useful ;)